# How to lookup options value by text in javascript IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to lookup a department ID via a department name in javascript.

The data is contained in a form select with options. The Department name is in the text and the id is the value.

Here is what I have and works perfectly in Chrome but doesn't work in IE.

```
var deptValue;
function getDepartmentValue (departmentText) {
    var deptOptions = document.getElementById("Departments");
    for (var i = 0; i < deptOptions.length; i++) {
        if (deptOptions[i].text == departmentText ) {
            deptValue = deptOptions[i].value; //set a global variable called deptValue
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that the problem is in the condition of my if statement

```
if (deptOptions[i].text == departmentText )
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Dan

Comment: It will be great if you use jquery for this operation and use $("#"+deptOptions[i].id).attr(text) this instead of deptOptions[i].text. This will work for the all browser.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Departments` is the `id` of the `select` element, this line:

```
var deptOptions = document.getElementById("Departments");
```

should be

```
var deptOptions = document.getElementById("Departments").options;
// ------------------------------------------------------^
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/abekap/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/abekap/1/edit) (I changed the global variable (!!!) into a return value)